# Minify angularjs calls from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have a question, is it possible to minify the calls to angularjs controller from html?

I am using something like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as vm'>
    <a href='' ng-repeat='l in vm.list' ng-click='vm.doSomething(l)'>
   ..... more html code
```

Controller:

```
(function(){
  function ctrl (service){
    var vm = this;
    vm.doSomething = function(l){
      ... do something
    }
  }
  ctrl.$inject= ["service"]
  angular.module("app").controller("ctrl",ctrl);
})();
```

Minification works ok in the controller, but, the calls from html are not minified, the ng-click='vm.doSomething(l)' is the same, is there a way (automated) to minify and link these calls and the resulting minification would be something like ng-click='vm.a(l)' and the ng-repeat='l in vm.z' ???

I hope I explained myself

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what is the build you are using gulp/grunt?

Comment: I am not using gulp/grunt I am using asp.net mvc bundling, but if it is necessary I can switch to gulp/grunt